# How to pass objects that are not of a primitive type (string, int, double, etc) in Java with private access modifier

Tags: java

I am trying to build a complete program from the partial code of a book. The difficulty is when a variable's modifier is set to `private`, I can't access it from the `main` method of my `BankTest` class after instantiating an object. Am confused on how to pass the `Dollar` Object as I can't set it to a primitive type like `double` or `float`.

Is there a way to set the `Dollar` object with `amount = 100`, so that when I run the `BankTest` class, I could get it to print the `getAmount = 100` ? I want to maintain the Dollar object as the parameter of a method if possible ?

```
final class BankTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
       BankAccount ba = new BankAccount();   
       Dollar d = new Dollar(100);
       //d.setAmount(100.00);  "IF class Dollar method is PUBLIC"
       //ba.deposit(d);   "How to set the value of Dollar Object ??
       System.out.println("Balance available: " + d.getAmount());  
    }

}

final class BankAccount {
     private Dollar balance;
     private boolean receipt;

public void deposit(Dollar amount, boolean receipt) {
  balance.add(amount);
 // if receipt == true, print receipt
}

public void deposit(Dollar amount) {
// validate and chain to base method
 deposit(amount, true);
}
}

final class Dollar {
    private double amount = 0;

    public Dollar(double _amount) {
        setAmount(_amount);
 }

 private void setAmount(double amt) {  //can only be called by within Dollar class

 // make sure amt is a valid currency amount
   amount= amt;
}

double getAmount() {
    return amount;
 }

public void add(Dollar amt) {
 // validate amt
 amount+= amt.getAmount();
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't get this. Why is `setAmount()` private?

Comment: Unless, you make that method `setAmount(double amt)` public, there is no way to set amount in your `Dollar` class. Why you did that?

Comment: I would suggest that `Dollar` should have a constructor taking the amount, and then that should be set as a `final` variable. I would use `BigDecimal` rather than `double` though...

Answer (score 0):

It seems Dollar was created to not be modified, but I wonder why the attribute is not `final` and why it can be modified by adding another Dollar object...
The idea is you have to create a new instance of Dollar every time you need a new value. Something similar happens with String and any primitive wrapper class (Integer, Float...).

As you are taking the code from a book you can decide how to deal with it: you can make the setter public or you can live with the current status and create a new object when needed.

You can already add an amount, so I think I'd modify the setter to public

Answer (score -1):

Simply make setAmount public.
And also add a getter. eg getAmout() that returns the current dollar value.

Setters and getters are meant to be public, else they are pointless.

You could also pass the dollar value in the constructor.

Comment: It's entirely reasonable to have non-public setters - either to restrict access within a package or inheritance hierarchy, or to avoid repeated logic (e.g. validation before setting a field).

Comment: By setter, i mean that the function is only doing "this.var = var".
If one wants to make some validation or something else, just make a function that has this purpose. Else it's confusing.
Personaly, when i call "setVar", i want the variable to be set, not the class to check if it's correct. If i wanted it, i'd have called checkVar(var) before setting it's value.
That's how the world works.
If you don't want your member to be accessible from outside, make it private / protected, without any setter

Comment: It may be how *your* world works, but it's certainly not how *my* world works. For example, I'm very happy that `StringBuilder.setLength` will throw an exception if you pass it a negative number - you would rather have a separate `checkLength` call but let `setLength` just change the state to something invalid? (As for making the field non-private - I prefer to separate my API from my implementation, thanks.)

Comment: Larta, I wanted to keep it as private for the setAmount() because that code is part of the private modifier section. I already put a comment on my code, if I made my code public, I would be able to access the method. Is there a way to pass the object as Dollar. This is the intention of my question.

Comment: Well, @Jon Skeet, you're right.
Also, i  didn't see you already had a getter. Indentation got me wrong.
The only way to do what you actually want to do is to pass the value to the constructor, as Jon Skeet suggest

Comment: Jon, looks like constructor would do the job as you mentioned. it would be public Dollar(double amount) {...}, and it would be able to access the private method setAmount(). The void add() in the Dollar class would be redundant. At the end, I still won't be able to pass the Dollar object as the parameter.  Sorry, I am not trying to be difficult, perhaps the author of the book didn't mean to build a complete code from the example. The example of the classes (BankAccount, Dollar) are from a book so I didn't modify any :)

Comment: @user3565385: "At the end, I still won't be able to pass the Dollar object as the parameter" - why not? That should be fine...

Comment: @tembok: No, you should only need to change `Dollar` and `BankTest`. But at this point you're trying to use Stack Overflow for interactive debugging, which it's really not suitable for. I suggest you go away and try various things, then come back with a new question.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, thanks for your hints. It looks like the example in the book won't work because I would need to abandon the BankAccount class at the end if I only change the Dollar class. I re-posted the new code. I think it doesn't matter now, I thought by re-posting the code, it would be clearer for everyone. Also to other contributors, thanks.